# python pandas dataframe - can't figure out how to lookup an index given a value from a df

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, lookup

I have 2 dataframes of numerical data. Given a value from one of the columns in the second df, I would like to look up the index for the value in the first df. More specifically, I would like to create a third df, which contains only index labels - using values from the second to look up its coordinates from the first.

```
listso = [[21,101],[22,110],[25,113],[24,112],[21,109],[28,108],[30,102],[26,106],[25,111],[24,110]]
data = pd.DataFrame(listso,index=list('abcdefghij'), columns=list('AB'))
rollmax = pd.DataFrame(data.rolling(center=False,window=5).max())
```

So for the third df, I hope to use the values from `rollmax` and figure out which row they showed up in `data`.  We can call this third df `indexlookup`.

For example, `rollmax.ix['j','A'] = 30`, so `indexlookup.ix['j','A'] = 'g'`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a Series with the indexing the other way around:

```
mapA = pd.Series(data.index, index=data.A)
```

Then `mapA[rollmax.ix['j','A']]` gives `'g'`.

Comment: John - good idea, thanks for responding. Do you think my best answer for a large data set is to go this route and live with looping over each column to create the "lookup" series?

Comment: Also - in the cases where there are duplicate values, is it possible to default to the first or last occurrence ?

Comment: @MJS: Yes I think this is a reasonable approach.  For the dupes thing, try http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html

Comment: Thanks again John. Last question - the mapA[rollmax.ix['j','A']] gives 'g' solution doesn't seem to translate to an entire dataframe. How can I fill the indexlookup dataframe with all of the appropriate index names from the rollmax:data mapping above ?

Comment: @MJS: I'll leave it to you to figure that one out, or post a new question about it if you're stuck.

Comment: That was my original question